# How to fix missing ippj-5.3.dll error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, error

I try to install OSGeo4W but when I tried to run it appeared an error message about ippj-5.3.dll is missing...
does anyone know what happen?

Comment: What system are you installing it on?

Comment: How did you install it? Did you choose the express option? Which packages did you try to install btw?

Comment: For me this error was originally related to trying to install osgeo4w without "Run as administrator". @R.K.'s answer helped

Comment: I have the same problem with an installation on Windows 7 64bits. I used the osgeo4w-setup.exe downloaded 24/08/2013 from http://hub.qgis.org/(exe has no version info) with "advanced install" option as an administrator and I choosed all packages. I get a missing ippj-5.3.dll when I run QGis (1.8) desktop and browser. I re-installed libjpeg package but the problem does persist. Does someone have an idea?
JCP

Answer (score 3):

You can try [reinstalling the libjpeg package](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/27) which will replace the jpeg_osgeo.dll with the non-IPP one. Or you could try removing it.

Comment: Furthermore, see also http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-libjpeg-ipp

Comment: My fresh install of QGIS 2.8.1 through osgeo4w was fixed by reinstalling libjpeg and uninstalling libjpeg-ipp.  Windows7, 32bit, advanced install.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be: delete the directory C:\OSGeo4W, start installation again and you should select only the package qgis or qgis-dev, do not click on any other package. Then everything runs as it should